# Standalone script creates unwanted directories

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I use the following code to import the relevant modules and prepare for a standalone script for QGIS 3.14:

```py
# Import modules
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

# Set a custom config path
QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis", True)
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append( "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis/python/plugins/" )

# Initialize the Processing plugin
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```

When I run this, a couple of directories (`oauth2-cache`, `processing`) and a database file (`qgis-auth`) are created in the same directory as the script.

**Is it possible to avoid creating these instead of having to remove them myself?**

Comment: It should be possible to set a custom target with INI files to change where these files/folders must be created, to a temporary directory). Side note, as you are using QGIS 3.14, did you look at qgis_process executable if you are using only qgsnativealgorithms?

Comment: @etrimaille - What is the "qgis_process executable"?

Comment: It's to be able to run QGIS Processing algorithms from command line, without opening QGIS Desktop https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#new-standalone-console-tool-for-running-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i just had to replace the config path as below. No more folders are made:

```
# Set a custom config path
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```